# Select yes as an option in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, openvpn

I have been working on a pipeline to create easy-rsa certificates, it was working fine but recently it failed with the error:

```
You are about to sign the following certificate.
Please check over the details shown below for accuracy. Note that this request
has not been cryptographically verified. Please be sure it came from a trusted
source or that you have verified the request checksum with the sender.

Request subject, to be signed as a client certificate for 825 days:

subject=
    commonName                = joni.lehto


Type the word 'yes' to continue, or any other input to abort.
  Confirm request details: 

Notice
------
Aborting without confirmation.
```

Since I can't type 'yes' because it is a github actions pipeline I am stuck, can anyone please help me out, here's the yaml for the step:

```
  - name: Creating Client Certificate and key
    run: | 
     sudo su -
     cd easyrsa3
     yes | ./easyrsa --passout=file:pki/file.txt build-client-full ${{ github.event.inputs.username }}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with openvpn. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try first the same `./easyrsa` with the [`--batch` option](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/d7aa481587f34788560971ca8c0c848411f684be/easyrsa3/easyrsa#L455).

```
--batch         : set automatic (no-prompts when possible) mode
```

That should avoid this prompt, allowing your GitHub Action to proceed.